# Adding logic to controller expression

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs for creating a website with multilangual support.

So this website has a list of services. Each service has a name in several languages and a price. I want to change the name of each service by changing the language.

So I have following code written:

```
myApp.controller('ServiceCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'languageService', function($scope, $http, languageService) {
var url = '../html/getServices.php';
//Getting following JSON:
//{"id":"1","ru":"russianNameOfAService","en":"englishNameOfAService","pr":"priceOfAService"}
$http.get(url).success(function(resp) {
    $scope.services = resp;
});
$scope.langService = languageService;
$scope.$watch(function() {
   return $scope.langService.getLang();
}, function(newLang) {
    if (newLang == 'en') {
        $('.serviceName').append('{{service.en}}');
    } else if (newLang == 'ru') {
        $('.serviceName').append('{{service.ru}}');
    }
});
}])

myApp.service('languageService' , function() {
var language = 'en';
return {
    getLang: function() {
        return language;
    },
    setLang: function(ind) {
          if (ind == '0') {
              language = 'en';
          } else if (ind == '1') {
              language = 'ru';
          }
    }
};
})
```

So this was my angular code. And this is my html:

```
<div class="service" ng-repeat="service in services" id="{{service.id}}">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="serviceName"></div>
                <div class="servicePrice">{{service.pr}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So why it does not work, or what is the best way to change dinamically the expression inside the .serviceName div.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to fix your watch, and update a variable on the scope with the current language.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
   return $scope.langService.getLang();
}, function(newLang) {
       $scope.currentLanguage=newLang;
});
```

and then in the html use interpolation

`<div class="serviceName">{{currentLanguage}}</div>`